# Access linked table Connect property corrupted - How to fix (or delete)?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have two Access (2016) databases on a company server. In database 'A' there is code that creates a linked table (in 'A') to a table in database 'B', performs some actions in database 'A' using the data in the linked table then deletes the linked table.

This has worked perfectly for several months but a couple of days ago it fell over.

On investigation I see that the linked table (in 'A') was not deleted, but the connection property of the table was reset to an empty string.
If I try to delete the linked table (in 'A') via the navigation pane I get the error 'Invalid use of Null'.

I've tried using code to update/restore the 'connection' property but that doesn't work.

I now have a table that I cannot delete.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can delete the table?

Comment: Have you done a Compact & Repair?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't work.... but see answer from Gord Thompson below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've tried using code to update/restore the 'connection' property but that doesn't work.

I was able to recreate your issue by hacking an .accdb file and setting the `.Connect` property of a linked table to `Null`. Although ...

- I was unable to delete the link (I got "Invalid use of Null", same as you), and
- Compact and Repair Database did not fix the problem

... I *was* able to revive the link with the following VBA code:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub ReviveBadLink()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Dim tbd As DAO.TableDef
    Set tbd = cdb.TableDefs("Clients")
    tbd.Connect = ";Database=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb"
    tbd.RefreshLink
End Sub
```

Once the link was revived I could then delete it as usual.

Comment: That has fixed the problem. Table now deleted. Thank you, Gord.

Comment: Mark the response as the answer